# expression syntax within ng-click

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have 2 variables wkidx and dyidx

I am trying to create multiple collapseable elements on the same page using the angular ui bootstrap directive and I have the following element

```
<a 
    href=""
    class=""
    ng-click="isCollapsed{{wkidx}}{{dyidx}}  = !isCollapsed{{wkidx}}{{dyidx}}">
    Blah
</a>
```

now this outputs what I want it to to the dom (ie it appends the variable values to iscollapsed) but I get a syntax error like so

```
Syntax Error
error in component $parse
Syntax Error: Token 'wkidx' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

I tried reading the page that the error page links to but it didn't really make things clearer for me.  I have tried numerous variations and they either dont give an error but dont append the values or they append the values but throw a syntax error

thankyou for the help here is were I am at but I am getting errors for probably obvious reasons

*html*

```
<div
    ng-repeat="session in day.sessions"
    ng-init="ssnidx = $index">

    <a
    href=""
    class=""
    ng-click="setCollapsed(!isCollapsed(wkidx, dyidx), wkidx, dyidx)">
    </a>

    <div
        collapse="I DONT KNOW WHAT SHOULD GO HERE">
            <p>hello from the collapsed div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*app.js*

```
$scope.setCollapsed = function(value, wkidx, dyidx) {

    };

$scope.isCollapsed = function(wkidx, dyidx) {
   if (isCollapsed + wkidx + dyidx) {
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid expression for ng-click. You'd better to create to methods in your `$scope`:

`setCollapsed(value, wkidx, dyidx)` and `isCollapsed(wkidx, dyidx)`

```
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.setCollapsed = function(value, wkidx, dyidx) {
       //...
   };
   $scope.isCollapsed = function(wkidx, dyidx) {
       //...
   };
}
```

---

```
<a 
    href=""
    class=""
    ng-click="setCollapsed(!isCollapsed(wkidx, dyidx), wkidx, dyidx)>
    Blah
</a>
```

Assuming, that `wkidx` and `dyidx` are atached to `$scope`

---

**Answering to your updated question:**

```
<div
    ng-repeat="session in day.sessions"
    ng-init="ssnidx = $index">

    <a
    href=""
    class=""
    ng-click="setCollapsed(!isCollapsed(wkidx, dyidx), wkidx, dyidx)">
    </a>

    <div
        ng-show="isCollaspsed(wkidx, dyidx)">
            <p>hello from the collapsed div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I understand that its not a valid expression for ng-click do you mind expanding on your solution a bit more though? do you mean create two methods to set the value in the controller?  I am confused as to how to go about that sorry

Comment: @Ir1sh Yes, I mean to create these methods in your controller.

Comment: and have them return the correct string?  How do you ensure they are called as soon as the <a> element is created?

Comment: @Ir1sh angularjs will ensure :).

Comment: Ok I am sorry I tried to figure it out myself but what should the two functions be returning?

Comment: @Ir1sh ```setCollapsed``` may return nothing (i. e. ```void```), ```isCollasped``` - boolean value (```true``` if item with coordinates ```wkidx``` x ```dyidx``` is collapsed)

Comment: Thanks again for your help an patience, I have edited the question with what I am trying to do based on your advice but apparently I have no idea what I am doing lol as I dont think I am close.  I am very new to angular and js in general

Comment: @Ir1sh Updated answer, using simple [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) directive, assuming you have some collapse directive with similar behavior. Also, checkout this [lib](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/accordion)

Comment: yeah its the angular-ui bootstrap collapse directive I am trying to use I will have a look at the accordion instead and see if that will work as I am still getting isCollapsed is undefined from the controller

Comment: The accordion works as needed I dont know why I went for the collapse first I use the accordion elsewhere on the site. thank you for your patient advice